# Spring Boot Webflux controller different responses for different media types

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am building a REST application with Spring Boot and Webflux. There will be number of different endpoints that are will return a JSON resources.
Also, there is a requirement that the endpoints should be capable of returning different responses when:

- `Accept: application/json` then JSON response
- `Accept: text/html` then simple HTML page, where response JSON is formatted and simple CSS applied.

As there can be 100+ endpoints then it would be nice if this could be done dynamically instead of creating two `@RequestMapping` methods for each media type.

How could this be solved using Spring Boot and Webflux?

I have searched Google and have few ideas of using ByteBuddy to dynamically create the `text/html` endpoints.
If just adding `produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE}` then I get error in logs:
`no encoder for with preset Content-Type 'null'`

Comment: `produces` doesn't do what you think it does, it only is used for mapping **Not** for enforcing a return type. If you want 1 controller to do both, stop using `@RestController` and use a regular `@Controller` and return the name of the view and stuff your data in a `Model`. Then for the JSON case use a `MappingJackson2JsonView` to create JSON. Use a `ContentNegotationViewResolver` to select the proper View to use based on the content type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring WebFlux [Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) that "*a lightweight functional programming model in which functions are used to route and handle requests*" instead of `@RequestMapping`. It provides more flexible model and you can generate routes dynamically and reuse handlers.

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> setupRoutes() {
    String uri = "/test";
    return
            route(
                    POST(uri).and(accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)),
                    routeHandler::getHtml
            )
            .andRoute(
                    POST(uri).and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    routeHandler::getJson
            );
}
```